# How cann I add multiple classes with jquery?

Tags: jquery, class

I am generating buttons in a `for` loop and want to give them 2 classes. One of the classes is an element of an array.

But it wont work: the second class ends outside the markers, and it wont apply: `<button class="u," letter=""> u  </button>`. (the classes schould be "u" and "letter")

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(".playerLetters ").append(
    "<button class=  " + wordArray[i] + ", letter> " + wordArray[i] + "  </button>"
);
```

If I declare the letter class first, then the class from `wordArray[i]` wont work.

Comment: 1. To have spaces in an attribute you need the value to be surrounded in quotes. The string you generate doesn't have quotes around the value of `class`. 2. That's not even using jQuery to add the classes. You're simply using string concatenation to get some (invalid) HTML. Instead of using jQuery which would have avoided the whole thing.

Comment: So how can I do it if I dont use string concatenation? I mean, how can i make the class out of the content of the array?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add the classes `u` and `letter`, then you can do this by calling the function addClass (https://api.jquery.com/addClass/). According to the documentation:

> More than one class may be added at a time, separated by a space, to
> the set of matched elements, like so:
>
> $( "p" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );

So, in your case it would be:

```
$(".playerLetters ").addClass("u letter")
```

Or within your for loop:

```
$(".playerLetters ").addClass(wordArray[i] + " letter")
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you. So, you mean that I cant declare 2 (or more) classes when im creating the button via append()?

Comment: With the string `'<button class="' + wordArray[i] + ' letter"> ' + wordArray[i] + '  </button>'` I get this output using `append`: `<button class="u letter"> u  </button>`.

Comment: OK, those are many, many quotes... I am not sure if i get it right: the classes, that come from a variable, have to be in extra quotes. And all clases toghether also in quotes. Is it like that?